# Access Android activity stack from asynchronous thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-context

There are a ton of activity stack related questions on StackOverflow, but I didn't really see any that answered the question I have.  I'm working on an online game that (for now) has 3 different activities:

1. Login/Register
2. Menu (seen when logged in, includes "new game", "my stats", and a few other things...I'm just worried about the "new game" option for now.)
3. Game

The socket connection occurs in the login/register activity, which creates a custom service that runs in the background.  Since data can arrive at any point, the socket class I'm using has asynchronous response handlers.  This means I won't have access to the current context any time a message is received.

I need a way to figure out what the current context is when various message types are received so that I can handle the message accordingly.  For example, If a user's reached the game screen (#3 above) and gets one kind of message, it should simply tell the game screen to update with the new game state.  However, the user could be at the same game screen and receive a different type of message that says "close screens #3 and #2 and log the user out, returning them to screen #1".

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the current activity/context, determine if it's the right context for the current message, and how to handle it.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad way of implementing your game. You're essentially relying on the server to dictate everything. You should probably think about redesigning based on requests/responses. Holding a socket connection open for that long is usually a great place to have your application fail.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do -- design based upon requests/responses. Why would I want to close the connection between each request if each user has only 20-30 seconds to make a move against each other during a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ordered broadcast. Have the service send out the broadcast. Have each activity register for the broadcast, with whatever priority scheme you feel is appropriate. Have the activity that gets the broadcast call `abortBroadcast()` so the broadcast is stopped. That way, your service can "blindly" send out the event.

You might not even need it to be ordered in this case. I think that a `BroadcastReceiver` registered by an activity will only receive broadcasts if the activity is in the foreground (not paused).

I have a bit more written about the pattern [in a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html), though for a slightly different situation (either handle an event in an activity or raise a `Notification`).